# Running SQS consumer on ECS with numbers of desired count

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I do the test to run 2 difference consumers (let call it **Consumer-A** and **Consumer-B**) to the same Queue then I found that when **Consumer-A** pulling the message, **Consumer-B** doesn't pull the message and waiting for the Consumer-A to finish first and vice versa.
The process continues like this repeatedly. 
So my question are:

1. Does this normal in term of multiple SQS consumer? I found this which seem to answer this question but I'm not sure. [https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:~:text=Do%20Amazon%20SQS%20FIFO%20queues%20support%20multiple%20consumers%3F](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:%7E:text=Do%20Amazon%20SQS%20FIFO%20queues%20support%20multiple%20consumers%3F)
2. What if we try to run the SQS consumer on ECS (example: with 3 desired count), do we get 30 messages at a time or what?

Do you have any others solutions for scaling to consume more SQS message (not using Lambda would be great)?

Comment: You link to the docs of a FIFO queue, FIFO queues behave quite differently than normal queues in terms of concurrency, especially if you have only one message group. Do you actually have a FIFO queue? You can explicitly NOT consume messages from the same message group id in parallel because otherwise the order could not be guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the FIFO queue. So in term of FIFO queue like this, what is the technique to implement the concurrency. Without using Lambda would be great :).
Anyway thanks a lot for the comment.

Comment: Have multiple message group ids.